# Scanner's delimiter and regex in java

Tags: java, regex, delimiter

I'm trying to read input word by word, but couldn't figure out how to set Scanner's delimiter to whitespace and punctuation marks except ' (the single quote).
Here's what I got

```
BufferedReader input;
String line;
Scanner sc;
String word;
try  {
    input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
    while (input.ready()) {
        line = input.readLine();
        System.out.println("Current Line: " + line);
        sc  = new Scanner(line);
        sc.useDelimiter("\\W\\s^\'");
        //...
    }
}
//...
```

Comment: `String line = sc.nextLine();  ` `String[] words = line.split(" ");
`

Comment: @run and what about punctuation marks?

Comment: Yeah, my code was similar to this.

Comment: @Qwe you will get all the words including punctuation in `words` array, ex: `it's great` you will have `it's` and `great` words (in words array), or you want 3 words like `it` ,`s`, `great`. could u clear me please

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean?

```
sc.useDelimiter("\\W\\s^\'");
```

I would use

```
sc.useDelimiter("[^\\w']+");
```

---

```
String line= "Hello, world!\n 'Computer\n \n Science'\n Hell\n";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(line.split("[^\\w']+")));
```

prints

```
[Hello, world, 'Computer, Science', Hell]
```

---

```
String line= "Hello, world!\n 'Computer\n \n Science'\n Hell\n";
Scanner scan = new Scanner(line);
scan.useDelimiter("[^\\w']+");
while(scan.hasNext())
    System.out.print("|"+scan.next());
System.out.println("|");
```

prints

```
|Hello|world|'Computer|Science'|Hell|
```

Comment: I've tried this before and for some odd reason, it did seem to recognize the newline char. For example, if my input was something like this: "Hello, world!\n
Computer\n
\n
Science\n
Hell\n"

Comment: That is odd.  I have added an example.

Comment: Thanks Peter!! Your solution did work!! I just figured out I've made mistake somewhere else!

Comment: Also, I was wondering if I want to add one more condition to the delimiter that is the period is considered a delimiter if only it's followed by a non-word char, do I write it like this: scan.useDelimiter("[^\\w']+[.\\W]");?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the Tokenizer like that:

```
StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer("a|b|c");

while(st1.hasMoreTokens())
  System.out.println(st1.nextToken());
```

Hope that could help you in your case.